# MissingExceptionMethod error when calling token endpoint

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, openiddict

Okay,
I have a .NET Core project that uses Openiddict for token authorization. It's been working great until today when I'm suddenly getting MissingExceptionMethod errors. The really weird part is that the same thing happens on a version of the code that worked flawlessly last week. It's like it suddenly just broke with nothing changing. Strangely, this has happened before with Openiddict and an update fixed it but this time there is no update available. I'm using .NET Core 1.1.1, Identity Framework 1.1.1, and Openiddict 10.0.-beta2-0584.

Here's the full error:

```
    System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Primitives.OpenIdConnectResponse.set_RedirectUri(System.String)'.
   at AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server.OpenIdConnectServerHandler.<HandleSignInAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server.OpenIdConnectServerHandler.HandleSignInAsync(AuthenticationTicket ticket)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.<SignInAsync>d__66.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Authentication.Internal.DefaultAuthenticationManager.<SignInAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.SignInResult.<ExecuteResultAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeResultAsync>d__30.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>d__28.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>d__22.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeAsync>d__20.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.<Invoke>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware.<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
```

Here's the token endpoint code:

```
[HttpPost("token"), Produces("application/json")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Token(OpenIdConnectRequest request, string permissions, string appId)
{
    Debug.Assert(request.IsTokenRequest(),
        "The OpenIddict binder for ASP.NET Core MVC is not registered. " +
        "Make sure services.AddOpenIddict().AddMvcBinders() is correctly called.");

    if (request.IsPasswordGrantType())
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(request.Username);

        var accountTest = await TestAccount(request, user);
        if (accountTest != null)
            return BadRequest(accountTest.ErrorDescription);

        // Create a new authentication ticket.
        AuthenticationTicket ticket;
        if (permissions != null && permissions.ToLower() == "ui")
            ticket = await CreateTicketAsync(request, user, appId, null, true);
        else
            ticket = await CreateTicketAsync(request, user, appId, null, false);

        return SignIn(ticket.Principal, ticket.Properties, ticket.AuthenticationScheme);
    }

    return BadRequest("UNABLETOLOGIN");
```

The fact that it appeared to be looking for Redirect code made me wonder if all of a sudden it was trying to redirect on an error instead of return a status code but I haven't changed anything there in a long time. Here's the initialization code for Openiddict, etc.:

```
services.AddDbContext<AxiomIdentityDbContext>(builder =>
{
    builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
    builder.UseOpenIddict();
});

services.AddIdentity<AxiomApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
{
    options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
    options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
    options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
    options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
})
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AxiomIdentityDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ClaimsIdentity.UserNameClaimType = OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Name;
    options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType = OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Subject;

    options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
    {
        OnRedirectToLogin = async ctx =>
        {
            if (ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(configuration["Routes:AxiomApiRoute"]) &&
                ctx.Response.StatusCode == 200)
            {
                ctx.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
                var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.Join(",", ctx.Request.Cookies.Keys));
                await ctx.Response.Body.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
            }
            else
            {
                ctx.Response.Redirect(ctx.RedirectUri);
            }
        }
    };

    options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.CookieSecure = CookieSecurePolicy.None;
    options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.CookieHttpOnly = false;
});

services.AddOpenIddict(options =>
{
    options.AddEntityFrameworkCoreStores<AxiomIdentityDbContext>();
    options.AddMvcBinders();
    options.EnableTokenEndpoint("/api/authorization/token");
    options.EnableUserinfoEndpoint("/api/authorization/userinfo");
    options.AllowPasswordFlow();
    options.DisableHttpsRequirement();
    options.AllowRefreshTokenFlow();
    options.SetAccessTokenLifetime(new TimeSpan(0, 3600, 0));
    options.SetRefreshTokenLifetime(new TimeSpan(30, 0, 0, 0));
});

services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(config =>
{
    config.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.Events =
        new CookieAuthenticationEvents()
        {
            OnRedirectToLogin = (ctx) =>
            {
                if (ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api") && ctx.Response.StatusCode == 200)
                {
                    ctx.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                }

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            },
            OnRedirectToAccessDenied = (ctx) =>
            {
                if (ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api") && ctx.Response.StatusCode == 200)
                {
                    ctx.Response.StatusCode = 403;
                }

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };

});
```

Any ideas where this error could be coming from?

**Update - Here's the csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard1.6</TargetFramework>
    <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
    <AssemblyName>Axiom.Web.Api.Authentication</AssemblyName>
    <PackageId>Axiom.Web.Api.Authentication</PackageId>
    <NetStandardImplicitPackageVersion>1.6.1</NetStandardImplicitPackageVersion>
    <PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);dnxcore50</PackageTargetFallback>
    <GenerateAssemblyConfigurationAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyConfigurationAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyCompanyAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyCompanyAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyProductAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyProductAttribute>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Axiom.Common.Web\Axiom.Common.Web.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Axiom.Services.Interfaces\Axiom.Services.Interfaces.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Axiom.Services.Implementations\Axiom.Services.Implementations.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Axiom.DataAccess.EntityFramework\Axiom.DataAccess.EntityFramework.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="AspNet.Security.OAuth.Validation" Version="1.0.0-beta1-final" />
    <PackageReference Include="OpenIddict" Version="1.0.0-beta2-0584" />
    <PackageReference Include="OpenIddict.Mvc" Version="1.0.0-beta2-0584" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="5.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions" Version="1.1.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: There is some version mismatch between packages.

Comment: .-beta2 is most likely the corporate.

Comment: Could you please share your project.json/.csproj file?

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII Any particular reason why? It's been working pretty well until now.

Comment: I'm really tempted to say it's indeed a version mismatch. Can you please try using the latest OpenIddict version everywhere? At the time of writing, it's `1.0.0-beta2-0594`.

Comment: @Pinpoint Turns out you're right, it was a mismatch. One reference was set to a wildcard and the rest were hardcoded at 1.0.0-beta2-0584. Go ahead and create an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks (and to you too Pawel)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you're seeing is caused by a version mismatch: make sure all your projects are referencing the latest bits (`1.0.0-beta2-0584`) and it should work.